# Incremental annotation processing requested

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

```
 private java.util.List<java.lang.String> farmerVillage;
```

[WARN] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: androidx.room.RoomProcessor (DYNAMIC).

Entity

```
@Entity
data class ConnectedFarmer(
    @PrimaryKey
    val farmerCode: String,
    var farmerVillage: List<String>
)
```

Room Db-->

```
@Database(entities = [ ConnectedFarmer::class], version = 2, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(ListTypeConverter::class)
abstract class FarmerAppDb : RoomDatabase() {.......}
```

ListTypeConverter-->

```
class ListTypeConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromString(value: String?): ArrayList<String> {
        val listType =object :TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.type
        return Gson().fromJson(value, listType)
    }
    @TypeConverter
    fun frmArrayList(list: ArrayList<String?>): String {
        return Gson().toJson(list)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you update you question to clarify what your question is? Posting an example of your code is useful, but for someone to reply and offer help we need to know what you need help with? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

In your android kotlin project gradle.properties file

> Enable Kapt Incremental annotation processing requeste

```
kapt.incremental.apt=true
```

**What's the purpose of incremental processing?**

> From version 1.3.30+, incremental processing allowed modules not to be
> entirely processed again each time a change occurs, giving the build
> process a better performance:

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html#incremental-annotation-processing-since-1330 - Incremental annotation processing is enabled by default starting from version 1.3.50